Bogus fee to "register" battery
A friend took her car back to the dealer for oil change and state inspection. First they told her the battery needed to be replaced, and when she said it was bought from AAA only a few months ago they said they needed to charge her $100 to "register" it or they could never do any work on it. (What work would they do on a battery anyway?) I think she got scammed.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

It's a Mini Cooper, not sure what year- about 3-4 years old, so a 2021 or newer.

Also it's a manual transmission, not that it should matter relative to charging a fee because the battery wasn't bought from Mini.

I would agree with you from what you are saying. I was asking about the vehicle information because "some" vehicles (BMW among them) require the battery be coded to the vehicle when replaced. It is my understanding, in order for the vehicle to start in the first place the battery has to be coded, so from what you said, it sounds like they were charging a pink tax on her. It would be hard for me or anyone on here to say for sure, though.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Apparently some Minis too. More info here: https://www.mini2.com/threads/register-a-new-battery-how.265618/

@MTA - Mini's are made by BMW, thus the reason I mentioned what I did.

Thanks for the answer! Registration now makes more sense, but $109.95 seems like extortion.

Modern BMW vehicles (new Minis are made by BMW) have a computer-controlled alternator that adjusts its charging profile based on the battery size, type, and age. When they are saying they need to register it, they are programming the computer with this information for the new battery.
If you don't do this, the vehicle may use a suboptimal charging profile which could lead to premature battery wear, but other than that, has no real negative consequences to the vehicle.
This registration can be performed with BMW-specific scan tools, and doesn't necessarily need to be done at a dealer. You could get it done at an independent shop, or buy your own scan tool to do it yourself, but cheap, generic ones can't do it, you need one with this special capability.
So, to sum it up, yes, this is a real thing, but no, it's not a show-stopping issue, and certainly shouldn't prevent anyone from working on the vehicle. However, a dealer having a policy that they won't do work on a vehicle that had the battery replaced without registering it, wouldn't be particularly shocking.

Thanks for the info! Live and learn. The car was already at the dealer for routine maintenance when they noticed the new battery. Telling an elderly woman she needed to do this on the spot felt coercive to her and it was $109 she wasn't planning to spend. If it's just a matter of scanning some digits into the computer, that's a pretty high price. Just another thing to watch out for when you buy a car!

Completely agree, it takes about 5 minutes to do with a capable scan tool. I think they purposely price it just under what you would have to pay to buy a good enough scan tool to do the job.
